# Polars convert list of strings to list of categoricals

Tags: python-polars

I'm trying to improve performance of my polars code by converting a list of string to a list of categorical type for my tags column:

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b          │
│ --- ┆ ---        │
│ i64 ┆ list[str]  │
╞═════╪════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ ["a", "b"] │
│ 2   ┆ ["a"]      │
│ 3   ┆ ["c", "d"] │
└─────┴────────────┘
```

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[['a','b'],['a'],['c','d']]}) 

df.with_column(pl.col('tags').cast(pl.list(pl.Categorical)))
```

However I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert value 'Unknown' as a Literal
```

Does polars support lists of categoricals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polars does supports lists of Categoricals.

The issue is you're using `pl.list()` instead of `pl.List()` - datatypes start with uppercased letters.

```
>>> df.with_columns(pl.col('b').cast(pl.List(pl.Categorical)))
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬────────────┐
│ a   | b          │
│ --- | ---        │
│ i64 | list[cat]  │
╞═════╪════════════╡
│ 1   | ["a", "b"] │
│ 2   | ["a"]      │
│ 3   | ["c", "d"] │
└─────┴────────────┘
```

[`pl.list()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.list.html) is something different - it appears to be shorthand syntax for `pl.col().list()`

Comment: Thanks, is that why the error message was so cryptic?  Because pl.list() exists?

Comment: Exactly, yeah. You can select columns by type e.g. `df.select(pl.col(pl.Int64))` and to make a list you can `df.select(pl.col(pl.Int64).list())` - `pl.list()` is shorthand e.g. `df.select(pl.list(pl.Int64))` - so `pl.list(pl.Int64)` is a valid polars expression but `.cast()` doesn't understand it. Perhaps there could be some improvement on the error message for this type of case.